# count get collection and count query giving different results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So i am trying to get distinct collections like this

```
$data = DB::table('project_1_data')->distinct('Farmer_BankVerificationNumber_Farmer')->get();
```

But when i do a `count($data)` I get 1600 but when i run

```
$data = DB::table('project_1_data')->distinct('Farmer_BankVerificationNumber_Farmer')->count();
```

I get 1440. This is weird as i only want collection with distinct field 'Farmer_BankVerificationNumber_Farmer'. How do i write the query correctly?

Comment: No it does not actually

Comment: can you try using Collection ->count() after your ->get() instead of the PHP count() method? To see what it gives you.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question. I've updated with an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're asking your query to count the `distinct` values in the wrong place.

You need to tell your `count` parameter what field you would like to count on. So you'll basically ask the query to get the database information, separate the distinct values and then count how many of a specific field are distinct.

Your finished query should look like this:

```
$data = DB::table('project_1_data')
    ->distinct()
    ->count('Farmer_BankVerificationNumber_Farmer');
```

Comment: Already solved it but i will mark it as correct. Thanks